# how to use types created from persist template?

Tags: yesod

In my `Model.hs` I can successfully use the data types that correspond to my data tables that I describe in `config/models` file.

I would like to use these types in my other files, for example, in `Foundation.hs`.

Is there a module that I need to import or a function to call from the file where I need to use the types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why my first answer was deleted. Again, these types are visible in other files without importing anything. I posted the question too soon.